# HSQLDB: Caused by: Using MAX, but not Group By, and getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: expression not in aggregate or GROUP BY columns:

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, jpql

I am getting a JPQL syntax error message, and I am not sure how to fix the statement to get what I need.  I am using HSQLDB 2.4.0, and Hibernate 5.2.7.

For a given date, I am attempting to find the "**SudokuPuzzleModel**" with the largest **sudokuPuzzleID**.  Hence, the following Java/JPQL code:

```
static final private String queryByDateString = 
     "SELECT p FROM SudokuPuzzleModel p " +
     "WHERE p.sudokuPuzzleID = (" +
         "SELECT MAX(p.sudokuPuzzleID) FROM SudokuPuzzleModel pp " +
         "WHERE pp.publicationDate LIKE :publicationDate" +
     ")";

static protected String getQueryByDate() { return queryByDateString; }

static public SudokuPuzzleModel getPuzzleByDate(LocalDate publicationDate) {
    EntityManager entityManager = RootModel.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    SudokuPuzzleModel results = null;

    String queryString = getQueryByDate();
    String jpaParameter = "publicationDate";
    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString).setParameter(jpaParameter, publicationDate);
    results = (SudokuPuzzleModel) query.getSingleResult();

    entityManager.close();    
    return results;
}
```

I am not using a **GROUP BY** clause.  So any suggestions on how to modify the JPQL statement to get what I am after?

What I am after, the **SudokuPuzzleModel**, with the largest **sudokuPuzzleID**, that was published on the date that is being passed in.

FYI: The initial error message was "*ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - A problem occurred while trying to acquire a cached PreparedStatement in a background thread.*"
But, I believe that this is being caused by the syntax error.

Comment: Check the _real_ SQL that your obfuscation layer (=Hibernate) creates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like typo in your sql. Looks like you need MAX(pp.sudokuPuzzleID) instead of MAX(p.sudokuPuzzleID)?

Comment: Wow, that was quick.  You were so fast, that SO won't let me accept the answer for another 7 minutes.  I made that change, and the query runs fine now.  Thank-you.